# Allow mousepointer to be outside of screen boundaries

Tags: c#, xna, camera

I'm making a game using XNA 4.0 and c#. 
I just made my camera class and it's almost working as expected, except for one thing.
I can move with my mouse to rotate the camera but the problem is that when I get to the border of the screen, the mouse stops and so does the camera movement.

Is there any way to allow the mouse pointer to be outside of the screens boundaries to be able to keep tracking the pointer? Or is there any simpler way around?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

public class ArcBallCamera
{
    private float speeder = 100;
    public ArcBallCamera(float aspectRation, Vector3 lookAt)
        : this(aspectRation, MathHelper.PiOver4, lookAt, Vector3.Up, 0.1f, float.MaxValue) { }

    public ArcBallCamera(float aspectRatio, float fieldOfView, Vector3 lookAt, Vector3 up, float nearPlane, float farPlane)
    {
        this.aspectRatio = aspectRatio;
        this.fieldOfView = fieldOfView;
        this.lookAt = lookAt;
        this.nearPlane = nearPlane;
        this.farPlane = farPlane;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Recreates our view matrix, then signals that the view matrix
    /// is clean.
    /// </summary>
    public void ReCreateViewMatrix()
    {

        //Calculate the relative position of the camera                        
        position = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.Backward, Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(yaw, pitch, 0));
        //Convert the relative position to the absolute position
        position *= zoom;
        position += lookAt;

        //Calculate a new viewmatrix
        viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(position, lookAt, Vector3.Up);
        viewMatrixDirty = false;
    }




    /// <summary>
    /// Recreates our projection matrix, then signals that the projection
    /// matrix is clean.
    /// </summary>
    public void ReCreateProjectionMatrix()
    {
        projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(fieldOfView, AspectRatio, nearPlane, farPlane);
        projectionMatrixDirty = false;
    }

    #region HelperMethods

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves the camera and lookAt at to the right,
    /// as seen from the camera, while keeping the same height
    /// </summary>        
    public void MoveCameraRight(float amount)
    {
        Vector3 right = Vector3.Normalize(LookAt - Position); //calculate forward
        right = Vector3.Cross(right, Vector3.Up); //calculate the real right
        //right.Y = 0;
        right.Normalize();
        LookAt += right * amount;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves the camera and lookAt forward,
    /// as seen from the camera, while keeping the same height
    /// </summary>        
    public void MoveCameraForward(float amount)
    {
        Vector3 forward = Vector3.Normalize(LookAt - Position);
       // forward.Y = 0;
        forward.Normalize();
        LookAt += forward * amount;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Moves the camera and lookAt up or down,
    /// LOL
    /// </summary>        
    public void MoveCameraUp(float amount)
    {
        Vector3 up = Vector3.Normalize(LookAt - position);
        up = Vector3.Cross(up, Vector3.Left);   //Calculate the REAL FUCKING UP/DOWN
        up.X = 0;
        up.Z = 0;
        up.Normalize();
        LookAt += up * amount;
    }


    #endregion

    #region FieldsAndProperties
    //We don't need an update method because the camera only needs updating
    //when we change one of it's parameters.
    //We keep track if one of our matrices is dirty
    //and reacalculate that matrix when it is accesed.
    private bool viewMatrixDirty = true;
    private bool projectionMatrixDirty = true;

    public float MinPitch = -MathHelper.PiOver2 + 0.3f;
    public float MaxPitch = MathHelper.PiOver2 - 0.3f;

    private float pitch;
    public float Pitch
    {
        get { return pitch; }
        set
        {
            viewMatrixDirty = true;
            pitch = MathHelper.Clamp(value, MinPitch, MaxPitch);
        }
    }

    private float yaw;
    public float Yaw
    {
        get { return yaw; }
        set
        {
            viewMatrixDirty = true;
            yaw = value;
        }
    }

    private float fieldOfView;
    public float FieldOfView
    {
        get { return fieldOfView; }
        set
        {
            projectionMatrixDirty = true;
            fieldOfView = value;
        }
    }

    private float aspectRatio;
    public float AspectRatio
    {
        get { return aspectRatio; }
        set
        {
            projectionMatrixDirty = true;
            aspectRatio = value;
        }
    }

    private float nearPlane;
    public float NearPlane
    {
        get { return nearPlane; }
        set
        {
            projectionMatrixDirty = true;
            nearPlane = value;
        }
    }

    private float farPlane;
    public float FarPlane
    {
        get { return farPlane; }
        set
        {
            projectionMatrixDirty = true;
            farPlane = value;
        }
    }

    public float MinZoom = 1;
    public float MaxZoom = float.MaxValue;
    private float zoom = 1;
    public float Zoom
    {
        get { return zoom; }
        set
        {
            viewMatrixDirty = true;
            zoom = MathHelper.Clamp(value, MinZoom, MaxZoom);
        }
    }


    private Vector3 position;
    public Vector3 Position
    {
        get
        {
            if (viewMatrixDirty)
            {
                ReCreateViewMatrix();
            }
            return position;
        }
    }

    private Vector3 lookAt;
    public Vector3 LookAt
    {
        get { return lookAt; }
        set
        {
            viewMatrixDirty = true;
            lookAt = value;
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region ICamera Members
    public Matrix ViewProjectionMatrix
    {
        get { return ViewMatrix * ProjectionMatrix; }
    }

    private Matrix viewMatrix;
    public Matrix ViewMatrix
    {
        get
        {
            if (viewMatrixDirty)
            {
                ReCreateViewMatrix();
            }
            return viewMatrix;
        }
    }

    private Matrix projectionMatrix;
    public Matrix ProjectionMatrix
    {
        get
        {
            if (projectionMatrixDirty)
            {
                ReCreateProjectionMatrix();
            }
            return projectionMatrix;
        }
    }
    #endregion


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re[set the mouse position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mouse.setposition.aspx) for every frame.

Example:

```
// Center of the window
var resetPosition = new Point(WindowWidth / 2, WindowHeight / 2);

// Get the movement since the last frame
var mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
var mousePosition = new Point(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
var delta = mousePosition - resetPosition;

// Reset the mouse position
Mouse.SetPosition(resetPosition.X, resetPosition.Y);

// Use the delta
RotateCamera(delta);
```

Comment: But the the mouse would be stuck in the middle of the screen which will make it impossible to look around?

Comment: You need to fetch the mouse position *before* you reset it. I extended my answer.